# How to run a Power Shell script on EC2 Windows 2016 instance every time it starts and running

Tags: amazon-ec2

The requirement is to 1. start the EC2 Instance > 2. Run a Power Shell script > 3. Stop the EC2 instance on daily basis.
I have Lambda functions ready for 1 and 3 but I don’t know how to run Power Shell Script automatically every time after my EC2 starts up. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

[Option-1] To achieve this you can take help of Windows task scheduler.

Please refer: https://www.itechguides.com/schedule-a-powershell-script/

[Option-2] Also, if you want to try a different option, you can take help of maintenance window, and schedule a RUN command, to run Powershell script, any time between the start and stop of the instance.

Comment: Thanks X-Men. I scheduled my power shell script using test scheduler.

Comment: Happy to help "X"